# Как в калькуляторе поле ввода обвести красным в случае отсутствия значения

Tags: javascript, html

Калькулятор почти готов. Осталось сделать так, что бы в случае пустого поля ввода, оно обводилось красной линией. Думал сделать функцию в которой при отсутствии какого либо значения добавлялся бы CSS класс, но увы...

```js
let input1 = document.querySelector("#input1");
let input3 = document.querySelector("#input2");

let addBtn = document.querySelector("#add-btn");
let remBtn = document.querySelector("#rem-btn");
let mulBtn = document.querySelector("#mul-btn");
let divBtn = document.querySelector("#div-btn");
let reset = document.querySelector("#reset-btn");

addBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert(Number(input1.value) + Number(input2.value));
});

remBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert(input1.value - input2.value);
});

mulBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert(input1.value * input2.value);
});

divBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert(input1.value / input2.value);
});

reset.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (input1.value > 0, input3.value > 0) {
    input1.value = 0;
    input3.value = 0;
  }
})

/* <----НЕ РАБОТАЕТ--> */
let borderOne = function() {
  while (input1.value = "") {
    input1.classList.add('border')
  }
}
borderOne()

let borderTwo = function() {
  while (input3.value = "") {
    input1.classList.add('border')
  }
}
borderTwo()
```

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 12px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
Операнд 1: <input id="input1" type="text"> <br />
<span id="input1Error" class="error">Введите значение</span> <br /> Операнд 2: <input id="input2" type="text"> <br />
<span id="input2Error" class="error">Введите значение</span> <br />

<button id="add-btn">+</button>
<button id="rem-btn">-</button>
<button id="mul-btn">*</button>
<button id="div-btn">/</button>
<button id="reset-btn">reset</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно добавить проверку при потере фокуса инпутом:

```
 document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('focusout', validate);
})

function validate(event){
    const input = event.target;
    if(input.value == ''){
        input.classList.add('border');
    } else {
        input.classList.remove('border');
    }
}
```

```js
let input1 = document.querySelector("#input1");
let input3 = document.querySelector("#input2");

let addBtn = document.querySelector("#add-btn");
let remBtn = document.querySelector("#rem-btn");
let mulBtn = document.querySelector("#mul-btn");
let divBtn = document.querySelector("#div-btn");
let reset = document.querySelector("#reset-btn");

addBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert(Number(input1.value) + Number(input2.value));
});

remBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert(input1.value - input2.value);
});

mulBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert(input1.value * input2.value);
});

divBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert(input1.value / input2.value);
});

reset.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (input1.value > 0, input3.value > 0) {
    input1.value = 0;
    input3.value = 0;
  }
})

document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('focusout', validate);
})

function validate(event){
    const input = event.target;
    if(input.value == ''){
        input.classList.add('border');
    } else {
        input.classList.remove('border');
    }
}
```

```css
.border {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
Операнд 1: <input id="input1" type="text"> <br />
<span id="input1Error" class="error">Введите значение</span> <br /> Операнд 2: <input id="input2" type="text" required> <br />
<span id="input2Error" class="error">Введите значение</span> <br />

<button id="add-btn">+</button>
<button id="rem-btn">-</button>
<button id="mul-btn">*</button>
<button id="div-btn">/</button>
<button id="reset-btn">reset</button>
```